# Width issue with negative text indent in CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-indent

When I run the code below, I see a blue box on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <style type="text/css">
                a {display:block;background:blue; text-indent:-9999px; float:left;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a>Hello World</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How come if I change the text `Hello World` to `HelloWorld`, the blue box disappears?

**Additional Notes** - I am seeing this in google chrome.

Comment: Interesting. I also noticed that the calculated width of the element is 0 without a space and 40 with.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be Chrome specific. Maybe just a Chrome bug?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` makes it disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment, `white-space: nowrap` makes it disappear.

However, I'm not sure what's actually going on here. Chrome/Safari + Opera all behave in the same way and show the "blue box", whereas Firefox and IE7-9 do not show the blue box.

Your code: http://jsbin.com/igewuy

With the `white-space: nowrap` "fix": http://jsbin.com/igewuy/2